# Как объяснить постановку двоеточия

Tags: пунктуация

Сорока-белобока очень красивая птица: хвост у нее отливает красноватым и зеленоватым металлическим блеском, голова угольно-черная, на боках белые пятна.

Comment: Надо говорить: пожалуйста. На курсах ликбеза не учили вежливости? Небось ДЗ?

Comment: Это годовой диктант для 9 класса: http://ruslita.ru/masterskaya-uchitelya/vidy-kontrolya/204-godovye-diktanty-v-5-11-klassakh?start=4 - "Сорока-белобока". Вопрос "Объясните запятую!" - тоже оттуда.

Answer (score 2):

> *Двоеточие ставится после предложения, за которым следует одно или несколько предложений, не соединенных с первым посредством cоюзов и
>   заключающих в себе: а) разъяснение или раскрытие содержания того, о
>   чем говорится в первом предложении...*

(Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации, акад. справочник под ред. Лопатина)